# Filepicker.io - Disable flash fallback

Tags: filepicker.io

I'm wondering if it's possible to disable the flash fallback feature in Filepicker.io? If you happen to be running a flash blocker in your browser, you get an ugly flash icon when the modal for filepicker comes up. It would be nice if this feature could be disabled via either the Javascript options or the Dashboard. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to do it at the moment. Feel free to send an email to contact@filepicker.io with a screenshot so we can figure out next steps.

Comment: Hey, sorry for not responding sooner. I've sent an email to the above address with a screenshot of the issue. Thanks.